# Is it possible to render TeX math comments in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, tex

There is such an extension in VS: [TeX Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1305558.VsTeXCommentsExtension&ssr=false#qna) and the example:

[image]

I wonder if it's possible to do this in VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no extension for VSCode that does that, it may possible though see: [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/129933).

A good starting point will be to use something like: LaTeX Workshop's [preview](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Hover#previewing-equations) to display/overlay them over comments or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Comments in vscode support unicode characters. For easy conversion, you can use tools that convert tex symbols to unicode. An example of such is:

https://www.unicodeit.net/

As an alternative, you can search through the supported unicode characters for what you are seeking.
For instance:

suppose you have:

x^2 + y^2 = 1 +dx^2y^2

It is the case that each of these symbols exist in the list of supported unicode characters:

² + ² = 1 + ²²

Full tex rendering is only supported externally by extentensions, as you can see in the tex comments extension that you linked to.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33518426)