# Inserting Latex syntax as comment in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I use `Visual Studio code` for my `python` exercises.

I wonder if it is possible to include different mathematical expressions as comment in my `VS code` editor itself.

I searched over internet and found a similar thing here https://github.com/Segfaultt/VsTeXCommentsExtension-2022

However I could not find a way to install this in `VS code` work environment. When I searched for it in *view -> extensions* for this addin, `VS code` does not share any result.

Could you please help me to install this addin? Alternatively, is there any other way to write mathematical expressions in comments for various programming languages like `python`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to render TeX math comments in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767268/is-it-possible-to-render-tex-math-comments-in-vs-code). It says that this is currently not possible.... (currently is: November 2023)